# How much data is needed for transfer learning in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

The issue with medical datasets are low count of observations. I would like to utilize Transfer Learning with CNN to correctly predict illnesses based on either writings (i.e. paper Refining Parkinson’s neurological disorder identification through deep transfer learning), drawings (or possibly in future voice - with different NN than CNN).

I am looking for rule of thumb how many observations do we need to utilize TL over those datasets? What would be the optimal base dataset?

Should I use pretrained imagenet or try to utilize different datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally depends on how similar your new task is with respect to the task the network was originally trained on. Also, it depends on the model architecture and if/how many of the layers you are going to update using the new dataset.

Assume you have a convolutional neural network that was trained for ImageNet classification. Now, you want to specialize this network in distinguishing cats from dogs. You would replace the last layer (if it is a fully connected layer, you change $\mathbb{R}^{d, o}$, where $o$ is the number of output classes, such that $o=2$ for your new binary classification task). Then, you can probably get away with training it with ~500-5000 cats vs dog images. It's hard to be more specific, though because there is no hard and fast rule.